# Detect if an ethernet port is unplugged

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04

I want to trap the event of unplugging an ethernet port on a Linux Ubuntu 14.04.

I want to create a script that detect whenever an ethernet port is unplugged and write it to a log.

Which is the best way to trap such an event

Answer (score 1):

Just put an executable script inside `/etc/network/if-post-down.d`.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

if [[ "$IFACE" == "wlan0" ]]; then
    logger "The wlan0 interface is down!"
    # Do whatever you want here.
fi
```

Make sure to `chmod +x` it, also.

Read more about these events/scripts [here on the Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/OnNetworkConnectionRunScript).

Comment: I tried on a virtual machine and I disconnected the virtual ethernet but the script did not run. Any suggestion on how to debug? the script is executable